# Excel: Named cell auto Sum

Tags: excel

i have to cells with defined name like this

### A B C D

### 1 2 3 4

### name1

### 1 2 3 4

### 1 2 3 4

### 1 2 3 4

### 1 2 3 4

### name2

i want to autosum cells in the range between name1 and name2 of column C

Comment: If it doesn't need to be automated use a formula.

Comment: thx for your suggestion, but i can't understand what is forumla that i can use? and sure i need to autosum cells because in the future anyone can add new cells between these names and may be change the numbers

Comment: I just mean use a simple `SUM()` function. It will ignore text values. So if anyone adds a row between `name1` and `name2` it will still work. For example, `SUM(C2:C7)`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/lwcCw

take a look at this image, for example i want to make total I the sum between total I until total II

Comment: Interesting image. I like the rolling eyes.

Comment: hehehehehe yeah

Answer (score 2):

If **Name1** and **Name2** are contained in cells, then use:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C" & MATCH("Name1",C:C,0)+1 & ":C" & MATCH("Name2",C:C,0)))
```

[image]

If, however Name1 and Name2 are **Defined Names**, then all you need is:

```
=SUM(Name1:Name2)
```

Comment: thx for help but i mean that the cell taht has value "total I" it's defined name with "x" and the cell with value "total II" it's defined name with "xx"

so now i want to autosum the all rows between x and xx of column K

Comment: i tried the formula =SUM(INDIRECT("C" & MATCH("Name1",C:C,0)+1 & ":C" & MATCH("Name2",C:C,0)))

Comment: i tried the formula 

=SUM(INDIRECT("C" & MATCH("Name1",C:C,0)+1 & ":C" & MATCH("Name2",C:C,0)))


and always return 0

Comment: @user1549555  update your post with a picture of your data

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Don't check any images by this guy! He posted an illegitimate URL above. I'm reporting him.

Comment: @Brian first i am not guy